# simple substitution on equation giving dev a ride: finding $ B $ and $ D $ given $ A B = C D $ and $ E = D - B $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a developer working on some veterinary calculators.

I have found all the required equation substitutions needed for my app, but I left the last one for now and is giving me a bit of a doubt filled mind…

Is a simple two linear equations solved by substitution method,

I have:
$$ A B = C D $$
$$ E = D - B $$

I need to find $ B $ and $ D $…

Any ideas?
Is simple, high school stuff, but I have forgotten a bit.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have: $AB = CD$ and $E = D-B$.

Divide the first equation by $A$: $B = \frac{CD}{A}$, and substitute into the second.

This yields $E = D - \frac{CD}{A} = D(1-\frac{C}{A})$. Therefore $D = \frac{E}{1-\frac{C}{A}}$.

Finally backsubstitute to get $B = \frac{C}{A}\frac{E}{(1-\frac{C}{A})} = \frac{CE}{A-C}$